# Chessboardjs NPM package in react, referenceerror $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, chess, chessboard.js

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/chessboardjs package. I wrote simple react component to render the board, but it throws an error in the chessboardjs module: ReferenceError: $ is not defined. The component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Chess from 'chessboardjs';

export default class ChessBoard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="chessboard" style={{"width": "400px"}}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var board = Chess('chessboard');
    }
}
```

I already tried installing the JQuery npm package and import that in the ChessBoard component but it didn't work unfortunately.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should import the $, jQuery, window.jQuery variables into all modules.
If you use webpack1,you can try by this:

```
providePlugin = new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
  }),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new to react and the app doesn't use Webpack at the moment. Is there another way to include jQuery in all modules or is Webpack the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'
import Chess from 'chessboardjs';

window.$ = $
window.jQuery = $

export default class ChessBoard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="chessboard" style={{"width": "400px"}}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var board = Chess('chessboard');
    }
}
```